# How do I send an HTTP request to a load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created two EC2 instances for web server and one EC2 instance for db server.
I put php scripts on web server to get HTTP post variables to send SQL query to the db server.

I have created a load balancer and added the web server instances.

I have this address on my client side to get data from the web server.

```
http://aws_web_server_elastic_ip_address/app-get.php"
```

Now, If I have a load balancer then what is the address that the clients send requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have correctly added your EC2 instances to your load balancer, and have correctly mapped the ports during the creation of your load balancer, here are the steps for getting the correct url:
Log into AWS Management Console, go to "EC2" tab, and click the "Load Balancers" link on the left of the screen. Now, click on your load balancer.
Your url should be:
`http://<the value of the DNS Name column on your load balancer>/app-get.php`